# How to get list of root firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to get a list of one of my root nodes of my database

my database is set up like this

```
beans-card
       --user
           --008675
              --...
              --...
              --...
           --007865
              --...
              --...
              --...
```

and so on...
i'm trying to get a list of the user which is made up of 6 digit string.

my code to read is

```
 DatabaseReference list_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        list_db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                getAllTask(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

 private void getAllTask (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Users users = singleSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
        allUsers.add(users);

    }
    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,
            allUsers);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
}
```

and the error im currently getting is

```
11-28 13:44:38.622 23572-23572/ca.mobile.jenovaprojects.rewardsreader W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 778018 found on class ca.mobile.jenovaprojects.rewardsreader.main.models.Users
```

for each user thats in the database.

thanks for any insight

Answer (score 1):

To get those user 6 digit ids into a list, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("user");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String userId = ds.getKey();
            list.add(userId);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Now the `list` contains: `008675, 007865 and so on.`